# java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot be cast to org.springframework.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture

Tags: java, asynchronous, spring-boot, spring-data, future

I am trying to run a Spring Boot application with hibernate via Spring Data jpa. I have a "User" entity,

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    public long id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    public String name = "";
}
```

and an async "UserRepository" which extends Spring Data "Repository",

```
public interface UserRepository extends Repository<User, Long> {
    @Async
    ListenableFuture<User> save(User user);
}
```

However, when "save" is called,

```
ListenableFuture<User> futureCreated = userRepository.save(newUser);
                    futureCreated.addCallback(created -> {
                               // do something 
                            },
                            err -> {
                               // do something else
                            });
```

I got the following error,

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.***.User cannot be cast to org.springframework.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy51.save(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor$1.call(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:110)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My annotations on the application,

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
public class Application {
    // main
}
```

Any idea? Really appreciate your help!

Comment: I believe async processing on repositories only works for query methods. The save method is implemented by the `SimpleJpaRepository` and simply returns the user not another result.

Comment: Thanks for your help, @M.Deinum! I'm actually getting this error on query methods too. I have another "getByName" function in the UserRepository, and it yields the same error..

Comment: Ok. Are you using a version that actually supports this? Older versions of Spring Data don't support this feature.

Comment: @M.Deinum, I'm using Dijkstra-SR6, which seems to be the latest in maven central. For now I'll just wrap the regular queries with async executor as a workaround...

Comment: Which is a version not supporting that you need a newer one also that isn't the most recent (not by far) as you missed the Evans, Fowler and Gosling releases (the latter is the most recent version see http://spring.io/blog/2015/09/01/spring-data-release-train-gosling-goes-ga).

Comment: Indeed, Gosling-RELEASE is the latest version, thanks for the correction. I just tried the Gosling release but it failed with the same error. Also, in the original error message, seems like it tried to execute the query as an async task, but failed to cast the the result to a ListenableFuture, so the Async annotation seemed to work there.

Comment: But you shouldn't need an `@Async` at all.

Comment: Hmm, I was following the guide here http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-async

Comment: Also, I'm using Spring Data (and Spring Boot) with Vertx, not sure if it has something to do with that..

Comment: Try on any arbitrary method not on of the default methods, see if that works. Also I highly doubt it would work for a save method ...

Comment: Yea, I tried with my custom query "getByName", it didn't work. I searched around but didn't find similar issues. For now I'll just use an async executor wrapper. Thanks for your help, @M.Deinum!